# Expanding powers in an expression and Hold

Tags: replacement, expression-manipulation, hold

Let an expression like `-(1/2) + (3 x^5)/2`
be given.

How can this be turned into `-(1/2) + (3 x x x x x)/2`?

All powers of `x` shoud be decomposed into product form.

I tried using `/.Power[]` and `Hold[]` but this is tricky.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```
Defer[-(1/2) + (3 x^5)/2] /. x_^n_?Positive :> RuleCondition@Table[x, n] /. List -> Times
```

> -(1/2)+3/2 (x x x x x)

?

Comment: Yes, good idea. I had to replace 'n' by '{n}' in the table in Version 8.

Comment: Thanks, I was not aware of the `Defer´ command.

Comment: @fwgb you can use `HoldForm` too, depends of how long you want to keep it held. Defer is gone now so another evaluation will bring `x^5` back.

Answer (score 1):

```
exp = -(1/2) + (3 x^5)/2;

Block[{Power = (Inactive[Times] @@ Table[#, #2] &) }, exp] (* or *)
exp /. Power -> (Inactive[Times] @@ Table[#, #2] &)
```

both give

[image]